# android studio: single commit when pushed includes other previous 3 commits

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I checked out new branch from develop, and made a commit for a single file.When pushing, it also includes the top 3 commits from the tree shown. I only wanted the single commit I made in the new branch to be pushed

[image]

Comment: You can't only push the latest commit and not those before it.

Answer (score 0):

If this commit is not related to commits you don't want to push, you can do that and need to start with proper rebase.

In terminal it would be command:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

This will open editor with such content:

```
pick 11af733 Oldest commit
pick 085693f Some commit
pick d9242c1 Commit you want to push
```

Now you need change order to have commit you want to push on top. Then you can checkout it and push to specific branch

```
git checkout <sha of commit, in my case d9242c1>
git push origin HEAD:develop
```

You can do it from Android studio as well under **Git / Interactively Rebase from Here** to see similar screen.